# Gupshup whatsapp bot estimated implementation time

Tags: bots, chatbot, whatsapp, implementation, gupshup

Hello we are a small team looking to implement a Gupshup/Whatsapp bot.

We are wondering how long does it take for this kind of bot to setup and have in working order?

apologies if is not a technichal question, but we are not sure where else to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask Gupshup directly and they will be able to help better. From WhatsApp's perspective, once you create your account on Facebook Business Manager and add your WhatsApp number, it goes through an account review which typically takes around 2-3 days and once that is approved, you can start sending messages right away. However, some of these businesses like Gupshup have sandbox experiences at times that give you this experience within minutes without having to go through the entire flow.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the implementation. One is business registration with Whatsapp linked with vendor like Gupshup and the other is coding implementation.
These both can be achieved anywhere from one to two months depending on the use case.